# Get some data from the prevous month file into the report of current month

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I get data from a folder. Each month a new file is added. Within the rows of this table only the changes are added. So the data that is unchanged is not within the new file but need to be in the monthly report. I try to illustrate as good as I can below:

```
  Excel file 1 (January):

     |     A     |    B    |    C   |   D   |
  ------------------------------------------
   1 | Date      | Name    | Type   | Price |
  ------------------------------------------
   2 | 05/01/20  | NamOne  | T1     | 200   |
  ------------------------------------------
   3 | 05/01/20  | NamTwo  | T2     | 300   |
  ------------------------------------------
```

-

```
Excel file 2 (February):

     |     A     |    B    |    C   |   D   |
  ------------------------------------------
   1 | Date      | Name    | Type   | Price |
  ------------------------------------------
   2 | 05/02/20  | NamOne  | T2     | 300   |
  ------------------------------------------
```

In February the type of NamOne has changed, and therfore the price is also updated. However, NamTwo is not in the February report.

Is it possible to somehow automatically add data from the unchanged values from january without having to put it in the February file?

I would then need to create a report where in february I get Price of NamOne (300) (from February) + price of NamTwo (300) (data from january) = 600.

Is this somehow possible or do I have to put all the data all the time?

I hope it is not too confusing.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: For your report, you could combine all the tables and filter for the most recent `Date` for any `Name`. You could do this with `Power Query`, `VBA` or various other tools.

Comment: Hey @RonRosenfeld thanks for your reply. Sorry, forgot to mention that I am actually using Power query. I just do not know how to achieve this result. I am getting all the files from a specific folder into a power query to combine them. But how would I get the value from January (that are not updated in the file of February) into the february report?

Comment: In your report, you could use a filter to exclude anything later than February; then group what's left by Name and return just the latest.

Comment: Thanks again @RonRosenfeld . So when I add march do I need to redo the filters? No way I could do this dinamically?

Comment: You can do this dynamically with Power Query.